# Using A Specified Inner Product to Calculate Cos(θ)

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Hello I am getting stuck on this question:
[image: Specific Inner Product]

What I have done to attempt to solve this problem is use
u⋅v=|u||v|cosθ to solve for cosθ, but instead of standard dot product I was using the one specified in the question to calculate (u,v), (u,u) and (u,v) however I keep getting E while the answer is A. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your approach is correct, but did you take into account that the definition of $|u|$ and $|v|$ depend on your new inner product?

Comment: Yes, I was using the given definition of the inner product with u transpose, and u in place of v. Or is that incorrect?

Comment: Please take the time to type in critical parts of your questions instead luring them as images, which are neither searchable nor accessible to people using screen readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, 
$$
\cos(\theta)
=\frac{\langle u, v\rangle}{\lVert u\rVert\lVert w\rVert}
$$
Taking $u=\langle-1,1\rangle$ and $v=\langle 2,1\rangle$, one easily computes
\begin{align*}
\langle u,v\rangle
&= -9 &
\lVert u\rVert &=\sqrt{\langle u, u\rangle}
=\sqrt{9}=3 & 
\lVert v\rVert &=\sqrt{\langle v, v\rangle}
=\sqrt{36}=6
\end{align*}
Hence
$$
\cos(\theta)=-\frac{9}{18}=-\frac{1}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=(-1,1)$ and $v=(2,1)$. We will also write $M=\begin{bmatrix}7&1\\1&4\end{bmatrix}$. Then $Mu=(-6,3)$ and $u^\top Mu=6+3=9$. Thus, $|u|=\sqrt{9}=3$. We have $Mv=(15,6)$ and $v^\top Mv=36$ so $|v|=\sqrt{36}=6$. Finally, we have $u^\top Mv=-9$. Thus, $\langle u,v\rangle=-9=6\cdot 3\cos(\theta)$. Thus, $\cos(\theta)=\frac{-1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner product is
$$\langle u,v \rangle = u^T \begin{bmatrix} 7 & 1 \\1 & 4 \end{bmatrix} v,$$
so your new vector norm is 
$$| u| = \sqrt{\langle u, u \rangle} = \sqrt{u^T \begin{bmatrix} 7 & 1 \\1 & 4 \end{bmatrix} u}.$$
Then using the formula 
$$\langle u,v \rangle = |u| |v| \cos{\theta}$$
we have
$$\cos{\theta}= \frac{\langle u,v \rangle}{|u| |v|} = \frac{u^T \begin{bmatrix} 7 & 1 \\1 & 4 \end{bmatrix} v}{\sqrt{u^T \begin{bmatrix} 7 & 1 \\1 & 4 \end{bmatrix} u} \sqrt{v^T \begin{bmatrix} 7 & 1 \\1 & 4 \end{bmatrix} v}} = \frac{-9}{(3)(6)}  = -\frac{1}{2}.$$